# Como montar um inner join filtrando por um campo com valor minimo?

Tags: oracle

Queria montar um `inner join` que trouxesse somente os valores filtrados por um campo de minimo valor

```
select min(data_vencimento) from pagamento where cod_situacao = 3,
cli.cpf, cli.nome, con.data_inicio, con.data_fim,
sit.situacao, con.valor_mensalidade  from cliente cli 
inner join contrato con on con.cpf = cli.cpf
inner join pagamento pag on pag.COD_CONTRATO = con.COD_CONTRATO
inner join situacao sit on sit.cod = pag.cod_situacao;
```

Comment: Como foi feita suas tabelas? Onde você pega este valor minimo?

Comment: seria uma data_vencimento como varchar e os pagamentos sao gerados automaticamente no sistema c#.

Comment: tem situacao de pagamento: 1 = em aberto, 2 = pago, 3 vencido

Comment: gerei 5 pagamentos, deixei 3 em aberto, 1 vencido, 1 pago. Como exemplo :                                                                                 
   1º   Data_vencimento = 09/07/2017 em aberto 
     2° Data_vencimento = 09/08/2017 em aberto                                                                                     queria mostrar somento uma linha com o vencimento para  09/07/2017

Comment: @MarcusVinicius , já estudou álgebra relacional? SQL é uma implementação parcial dessa matemática, pode ajudar bastante nas suas consultas entender a parte algébrica de trás de tudo isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deveria fazer assim:

```
SELECT MIN(co.data_vencimento), c.cpf
FROM cliente c
INNER JOIN contrato co ON co.cpf = c.cpf 
INNER JOIN pagamento p ON p.COD_CONTRATO = co.COD_CONTRATO 
INNER JOIN situacao s ON s.cod = p.cod_situacao 
WHERE cod_situacao = 3
GROUP BY c.cpf
```

Levando em consideração que o campo "data_vencimento" existe na tabela "contrato" e que vc queira a menor data de vencimento por cliente.

Caso vc queira isso agrupado por contrato, deveria ser assim:

```
SELECT MIN(co.data_vencimento), con.cod
FROM cliente c
INNER JOIN contrato co ON co.cpf = c.cpf 
INNER JOIN pagamento p ON p.COD_CONTRATO = co.COD_CONTRATO 
INNER JOIN situacao s ON s.cod = p.cod_situacao 
WHERE cod_situacao = 3
GROUP BY co.cod
```

O importante aqui é entender que o "group by" junto com a função de agregacão "MIN" é o que vai te dar essa informação.

Abs!

Comment: Um subselect do tipo data_vencimento = (select min(data_vencimento) from ...) não resolve ?

Comment: Pode resolver mas vc está fazendo uma subquery o que traz uma complexidade maior para a sua query .. Fica ai mais uma opção para  escolha, se preferir usa subselect, não vejo problemas.